# Difference between array and ...array

Tags: javascript, v8

It may be stupid but I really stuck with ***dot dot dot array(...[ ])***

I was playing with arrays and I recently noticed a fact I don't understand.

Consider this function in Node.js environment:

```
function test(name, age, adress) {
    console.log(Array.from(arguments));
    console.log(...Array.from(arguments));
}
```

the output is:

```
// [ 'john', 25, 'new york' ]
// john 25 new york
```

I thought the second line was a concatenation(strng) of the array values ​​(arguments) until I execute this function in chrome's console:

[image: screenshot]

So my questions is:

- does the second output is an array ?
- If yes, what is the difference between these two arrays ?
- What ...[array] actually does ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: You're looking at the spread operator.

Comment: @Shadow it's not _an operator_ though, it's just a _spread syntax_.

Comment: Think of your second example as `console.log.apply(console, Array.from(arguments))`. See [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)